# why doesn't freeing the pointer that valgrinds says leaks memory, work

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, system-calls, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a simple version of shell and everything works fine except when an executable is not found there is a memory leak.
Valgrind says the leak comes from the function exe_find, from which I know the pointer:

the funtion exe_find:

```
/**
 * exe_find - creates the path of an executable.
 * @exe: executable to search for.
 *
 * Return: a pointer to the argument to be given to execve function.
 */
char *exe_find(char *exe)
{
    Node *head = linked_path(), *temp, *current;
    char *cwd = NULL, *exe_dir = NULL, *to_exe;
    int is_ok;

    temp = head;

    cwd = getcwd(cwd, 0); // this pointer is on the heap, but I can't seem to free it
    // when I free the pointer here it says no memory leaks possible
    // but that's illegal because a syscall still needs to point to this
    while (temp)
    {
        chdir(temp->key);
        is_ok = access(exe, F_OK);
        if (is_ok == -1)
        {
            current = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            free(current->key);
            free(current);
        }
        if (!is_ok)
        {
            exe_dir = temp->next->key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!exe_dir)
    {
        return (NULL);
    }

    chdir(cwd);
    to_exe = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(exe_dir) + strlen(exe) + 2));
    if (!to_exe)
        return (NULL);
    strcpy(to_exe, exe_dir);
    strcat(to_exe, "/");
    strcat(to_exe, exe);

    // otherwhise, I tried freeing exe, exe_dir and cwd, it doesn't do anything

    return (to_exe);
}
```

here's the valgrind message:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==19975==     in use at exit: 13 bytes in 1 blocks
==19975==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 29 frees, 6,793 bytes allocated
==19975== 
==19975== 13 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==19975==    at 0x483AD7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==19975==    by 0x4952EFF: getcwd (getcwd.c:84)
==19975==    by 0x1098C8: exe_find (main-2.h:80)
==19975==    by 0x109B58: displayAndRun (shell.c:75)
==19975==    by 0x109CD1: get_prompt (shell.c:122)
==19975==    by 0x109DBA: main (shell.c:154)
==19975== 
==19975== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19975==    definitely lost: 13 bytes in 1 blocks
==19975==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19975==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19975==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19975==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

here's displayAndRun:

```
/**
 * displayAndRun - waits for a user to enter a command and executes it.
 * @line: pointer to store the  address  of  the  buffer containing the text.
 * @id: child process id.
 * @args: shell arguments.
 *
 * Return: nothing.
 */
void displayAndRun(char *line, pid_t id, char **args)
{
    char *to_exe;

    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
    {
        if (id)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            printf("#cisfun$ ");
        }
        else
        {
            if (execve(args[0], args, NULL) == -1)
            {
                to_exe = exe_find(args[0]);
                if (!to_exe)
                    execute(1, args, line);
                if (execve(to_exe, args, NULL) == -1)
                    execute(1, args, line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's get_prompt:

```
/**
 * get_prompt - gets the command from the user.
 * @line: pointer to store the  address  of  the  buffer containing the text.
 * @n: address to size of line.
 *
 * Return: nothing.
 */
void get_prompt(char *line, size_t n)
{
    ssize_t nread;
    pid_t id;
    char **split;
    extern char **environ;
    int i;

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        if (!strncmp(line, "exit", 4))
        {
            free(line);
            exit(0);
        }

        split = strsplt(line, " \n", '\0');

        id = fork();
        if (id == -1)
            exit(98);

        if (!strncmp(line, "env", 3) && !id)
        {
            free(line);
            for (i = 0; environ[i]; i++)
                printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
            execute(0, split, NULL);
            exit(98);
        }
        displayAndRun(line, id, split);
        non_inter(line, split, id);
        execute(0, split, NULL);
    }
    free(line);
}
```

and main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *line;
    size_t n;

    if (argc != 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
        return (1);
    }
    n = 0;
    line = NULL;

    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        printf("#cisfun$\n");

    printf("#cisfun$ ");

    get_prompt(line, n);

    return (0);
}
```

the leak comes from when I use the function getcwd, but free'ing cwd doesn't work.
Can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thank you in advance

Comment: Is the source code of your shell open source (on https://github.com/ ...)? Are you allowed to download then study -for inspiration- the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)?

Comment: no i haven't pushed it to github yet because I still have some tasks to do

Comment: If you did push to github now, we might help you

Comment: okay thanks then i'll push to github now, will give you my username when I'm done

Comment: "*when I free the pointer here it says no memory leaks possible but that's illegal because a syscall still needs to point to this*." What does that mean? If you free it and then it says no leaks isn't that what you want?

Comment: @kaylum that pointer still needs to be used after the while loop to change back to the current directory, so free'ing it there on that lines gives: syscall points to addressable byte

Comment: Well then free it when it is no longer needed. Why can't that be done?

Comment: i did but it doesn't do anything, which i also don't understand why, it just still says 1 block is lost

Comment: Show that code. There are a few early exits in the function. So if you are freeing only at the end of the function then it still has chances to leak.

Comment: BTW I don't understand why you are using [chdir(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) in `exe_find`. In my opinion it is wrong (except for some `cd` shell builtin). And your code needs a lot more comments (explaining for each function what it is supposed to do)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch here's my github repo: https://github.com/mdesignscode/simple_shell

Comment: Are you allowed to study the source code of existing shells, like http://members.tip.net.au/%7Edbell/programs/sash-3.8.tar.gz ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i'm sorry about the comments, each function should have no more than 40 lines, but I will try to put some comments in and chdir(2) is my allowed syscall

Comment: Nope not allowed, i should come up with solutions myself

Comment: Replied to you email.